# How to add column name

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter

I have a dataset in which some columns have header but the other ones don't have. Therefore, I want to add column name only to those who doesn't have column name. I know how to add column names using header but  I would like to know how to do this using index so that I can add column names only to the empty ones. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop through df.columns checking whether there is a column name or if it is empty:

```
import pandas as pd

# create df with two empty columns
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2], 'b': [1,2], 'c': [1,2], 'd':[1,2]})
df.columns = ['', 'b', '', 'd']
```

df with empty columns:

> ```
>        b     d 
>  0  1  1  1  1  
>  1  2  2  2  2
> ```

```
# new of list columns names must be the same length as number of empty columns
empty_col_names = ['x', 'y']
new_col_names = []
count = 0

for item in df.columns:
    if item == '':
        new_col_names.append(empty_col_names[count])
        count += 1
    else:
        new_col_names.append(item)

df.columns = new_col_names
```

df with filled columns:

> ```
>     x  b  y  d
>  0  1  1  1  1
>  1  2  2  2  2
> ```

Comment: Yes it worked. Thank you for the help :)

Comment: You're welcome! Glad it helped